# GraphicsMagick: Cannot convert pdf to jpeg

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, graphicsmagick

I am trying to convert a pdf document ( 95 pages ) to multiple JPEG files, but getting error:

```
$gm convert -verbose -density 300 TESTIO.pdf +adjoin FOO-%02d.jpg
 [ghostscript library] "-q" "-dBATCH" "-dSAFER" "-dMaxBitmap=50000000" "-dNOPAUSE" "-sDEVICE=pnmraw" "-dTextAlphaBits=4" "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4" "-r300x300" "-sOutputFile=/tmp/gm2BfrxJ" "--" "/tmp/gmWNsJU0" "-c" "quit"Error: /ioerror in --showpage--
 Operand stack:
    1   true
 Execution stack:
    %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1862   1   3   %oparray_pop   1861   1   3   %oparray_pop   1845   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   24   1   95   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   1745   0   9   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
 Dictionary stack:
    --dict:1154/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:76/200(L)--   --dict:76/200(L)--   --dict:106/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:286/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:22/25(L)--   --dict:4/6(L)--   --dict:22/40(L)--
 Current allocation mode is local
 Last OS error: 28
 GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
 gm convert: Unexpected end-of-file (/tmp/gm2BfrxJ).
```

Here is the config for GraphicsMagick:

```
$gm version
GraphicsMagick 1.3.25 2016-09-05 Q8 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/
Copyright (C) 2002-2016 GraphicsMagick Group.
Additional copyrights and licenses apply to this software.
See http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/www/Copyright.html for details.

Feature Support:
  Native Thread Safe       yes
  Large Files (> 32 bit)   yes
  Large Memory (> 32 bit)  yes
  BZIP                     no
  DPS                      no
  FlashPix                 no
  FreeType                 no
  Ghostscript (Library)    yes
  JBIG                     no
  JPEG-2000                no
  JPEG                     yes
  Little CMS               no
  Loadable Modules         no
  OpenMP                   yes (200805)
  PNG                      no
  TIFF                     yes
  TRIO                     no
  UMEM                     no
  WebP                     no
  WMF                      no
  X11                      no
  XML                      no
  ZLIB                     no

Host type: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Configured using the command:
  ./configure  '--prefix=/usr/local' '--with-modules=yes' '--with-libtiff' '--with-jpeg' '--with-gslib'

Final Build Parameters:
  CC       = gcc -std=gnu99
  CFLAGS   = -fopenmp -g -O2 -Wall -pthread
  CPPFLAGS =
  CXX      = g++
  CXXFLAGS = -pthread
  LDFLAGS  =
  LIBS     = -ltiff -ljpeg -lgs -lm -lgomp -lpthread
```

also:

```
$ gs -version
GPL Ghostscript 9.20 (2016-09-26)
Copyright (C) 2016 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
```

Comment: Is you /tmp filesystem full?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are using an **ancient** version of Ghostscript in your GraphicsMagick. I know that version has returned 9.20, but if you look in the error log you posted you will see "GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1". So your GraphicsMagick installation is using 8.70.

This looks to me like its caused by the fact that all the output files are being sent to the same filename. The switch `-sOutputFile=/tmp/gm2BfrxJ` will write all the pages to a single file. If you want them to go to multiple files then you need to specify multiple page output, eg `-sOutputFile=/tmp/gm2BfrxJ-%d` or similar.

I suspect the problem is simply that GraphicsMagick isn't set up to deal with multiple page files like this. Do the conversion one page at a time. Or have Ghostscript render the pages to JPEG for you.

Comment: even though i installed Ghostscript 9.04, but it seems when i run the command : gm convert -density 300x300 TESTIO.pdf -resample 25 -scene 1 +adjoin pdf_conversion_%d.JPEG, GraphicsMagick is still looking for Ghostscript 8.7 , how can i compile GraphicsMagick WITH GhostScript 9.04. My compile, make, make install for GraphicsMagick is: ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-modules=yes --with-tiff --with-jpeg  --with-gslib, make , sudo make install

Comment: I can't tell you anything about GraphicsMagick, sorry. My suspicion would be that its using a Ghostscript shared object, possibly even that it ships one (which would be nasty).